# How to change a select box option when using jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

Here's what I'm trying to do:
You open the page and there's a select box where you choose option A, another select box, option B, appears and shows options depending on what option the user chose for A.

I managed to get this far with a little help, but I want to customise the select box and the only way I could find a way to do that which supports the onchange callback was implementing jQueryUI. I can get it to make option B appear, but it wont change the options.

Here's the (very messy) code I have so far:

```
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type' />
    <title>Jailbreak</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="scripts/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="scripts/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="scripts/ui.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select[name='select1']").selectmenu();
        $("select[name='select2']").selectmenu();   
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function Select1(){
    var phoneselect=document.getElementById("select1");
    var phoneid = phoneselect.options[phoneselect.selectedIndex].value;
    if( phoneid == 'p1' ){
    document.getElementById( 'select2' ).length=0;
    document.getElementById( 'select2' )[0]=new Option("1.1", "1.1", true, false);
    document.getElementById( 'select2' )[1]=new Option("1.2", "1.2", false, false);
    document.getElementById( 'select2' )[2]=new Option("1.3", "1.3", false, false);
    }
    else if(phoneid == 'p2' ){
    document.getElementById( 'select2' ).length=0;
    document.getElementById( 'select2' )[0]=new Option("1.2", "1.2", true, false);
    document.getElementById( 'select2' )[1]=new Option("1.3", "1.3", false, false);
    document.getElementById( 'select2' )[2]=new Option("1.4", "1.4", false, false);
    }
    $('#fwselector').show('slow', function() {
        });
}
</script>
<div id="mainimg"><img src="images/devices.png"/></div>
<div id="formcontainer">
    <form>
        <select id="select1" name="select1" onchange="Select1();">
            <option value="Phone" disabled="disabled" >Phone</option>
            <option value="p1">iPhone 2G</option>
            <option value="p2">iPhone 3G</option>
            <option value="p3">iPhone 3GS</option>
            <option value="p4">iPhone 4</option>
            <option value="p5">iPhone 4S</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <div id="fwselector" style="display: none">
        <select  name="select2" id="select2">
            <option value="Firmware" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Firmware</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I should mention that I'm not very familiar with anything other that HTML or CSS at all, I've just done this by merging things together from loads of different guides.

Thanks.

Comment: I see that caching variables in JavaScript is not your strength.

Comment: Truthfully, I really don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: That was honest! :) Ok, so I hope you will get some answers on this site. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://www.appelsiini.net/2010/jquery-chained-selects

Very simple solution to chained select boxes.

Comment: This is much simpler than what I've been trying to do, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many things we can do to simplify here.

```
// let's "cache" our selectors to make them fast
var $select1 = $("select[name=select1]")
var $select2 = $("select[name=select2]")

// lets create an object to store options based on value of select one
var options = {
   "value1": [
         {value: "sample1", text: "sample option #1"},
         {value: "sample2", text: "sample option #2"},
         {value: "sample3", text: "sample option #3"},
         {value: "sample4", text: "sample option #4"},
    ]
   "value2": [
         {value: "sample5", text: "sample option #5"},
         {value: "sample6", text: "sample option #6"},
         {value: "sample7", text: "sample option #7"},
         {value: "sample8", text: "sample option #8"},
    ]
}

$select1.change(function() {
   var val = $(this).val()
   $select2.empty(); // clear all options of $select2
   populateSelectBox2(val)
})

// add a specific option
function addOption(text, value) {
    $select2.append("<option>", {value: value, text: text})
}

// loop through possible answers and add each
function populateSelectBox2(val) {
 for (var i = 0; i < options[val].length; i++) {
   addOption(options[val][i].text, options[val][i].value);
 }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put this into my code and will it work with jQueryUI? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: After looking at this further I've decided that I'm not really sure how to use this..

Comment: To be clear this isn't necessarily drop in ready. It should work fine with jQuery UI. Drop it inside of the $(document).ready(function(){ }). I know you're not super familiar with front-end stuff, but give it a try. I tried to break it out into simple functions to make it easy to read. If you have a specific question let me know. Also, play with this a bit. See if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/74rBx/7/

Comment: Okay I've realised I'm a bit out of my depth, had no idea it would be this complicated. To put it simply, I'm not really sure how to make it do what I want it to do. On http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/ there's a dropdown of all the model names along with firmware. I want this to allow the user to select a iPhone/iPad/iPod model and it to show the relevant firmwares, then to show the available jailbreak. What I understand you have done: Create two lists for each value, phone and firmware. Then On changing select1 it empties select2 and populates it with val(?). To be continued...

Comment: ... And you've demonstrated how to add a specific option, but I don't know how I'd do that depending on the phone selected. Then you've showed a loop which I can't say I really understand. I really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: I'll show you an example on JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/74rBx/11/ Try messing with that and see if you can get it to do what you want to do. Best of luck. The options variable creates an array of the new options, based on the value that's selected in the first select box.

Comment: Thanks that has really helped. I promise this is my last question. When I try and put it into my code firebug says 'newOptions is undefined for (var i = 0; i < newOptions.length; i++) {'. 

I have the jQuery from jsfiddle in script tags in the head.

Comment: Well. JSFiddle is acting up right now, so I can't see it, but my best guess is that either your options variable is not setup properly or the value attributes on your options are not setup properly. Here's how you can test what is wrong. Right before var newOptions = options[value] add this line alert(value);. Does that value match one of the options the options variable. (You probably don't know what I mean, but try it).

Comment: So if your options looked something like this. var options = {"phone1:[{text:"1",value:"2"}]}. The value that gets alerted would need to be phone1 to match. If it does match then it's something else.